# is there any plugin or script where we can support all HTML 5 input type fields? Please suggest

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to support all **(HTML5 from fields with javascript or 
jquery)** with all **standard browsers and devices?**

Fields examples:

```
<input type="search">
<input type="date">
<input type="email">
<input type="url">
<input type="number">
<input type="range">
<input type="time">
<input type="color">
<input type="tel">
```

Comment: Not without an external Javscript plugin/library, but that would be off-topic to ask on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

For `email`, `number`, `tel`, `url` use [Mask plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)
For `date`, `time` use [Date plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/)
For `range` use [Range plugin](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range)